# Number of chiral centers in Proline

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I think it's two, but I am not able to access/find any information on the net that supports my claim or justifies why it's wrong.

One chiral center is the obvious carbon attached to $\text{-(COOH)}$ group. I think another one is the secondary Nitrogen because it has three different groups attached to it + a lone pair. Moreover, it's also a part of a cyclic ring structure so that should slow down Nitrogen Inversion.

What's the actual answer to the above mentioned question and why?

Comment: I think you would need stronger obstacle to affect nitrogen  inversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the conceptual perspective applying [(CIP)-rules](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jchemed.9b00924), you are right; beside the carbon atom both $\alpha$ to nitrogen and the carboxylate, the nitrogen may be either *up* or *down* the plane of the cycle -- and given the pattern of substitution (including the free electron pair on $\ce{N}$), there could be diastereomers of proline.

However *in praxi* there are not.  Embedded in a conformational *flexible*  five membered cycle (with little cyclic strain, compared to cycles of four or three atoms) with single bonds only, the two forms of the free electron pair *up* or *down* interconvert into each other so rapidly, that this averages out *like* there were no stereogenic centre present.  (Build molecular models and try this manually.)  This is reason the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramidal_inversion#Nitrogen_inversion) states *as general rule*

> «For a compound that would otherwise be chiral due to a nitrogen stereocenter, nitrogen inversion provides a low energy pathway for racemization, usually making chiral resolution impossible.»
>
> [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramidal_inversion#Nitrogen_inversion)

(For free ammonia at room temperature, the same page states 30 billion flips per second.)  Thus *for proline*, count ***only one stereogenic centre***.

---

Note, *rigid* cycles may prevent this flips to occur (e.g., [Tröger bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%B6ger%27s_base)).